# how to search data from multiple table in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm Trying Fetch data or search data from multiple table,

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $query = $_POST['query'];
  $min_length = 1;
  if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){
    $query = htmlspecialchars($query);
    $result = $con->prepare("SELECT bike_showroom.token_id, bike_showroom.id, bike_showroom.ad_id, bike_showroom.title, bike_showroom.category, bike_showroom.name, bike_showroom.image, bike_showroom.content, bike_showroom.offer, bike_showroom.note, bike_showroom.price, bike_showroom.address, bike_showroom.contact_no, bike_showroom.email_id,bike_showroom.timestamp, bike_showroom.status FROM bike_showroom WHERE (title LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (category LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (name LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (address LIKE '%".$query."%')
    UNION 
    SELECT college.token_id, college.id, college.ad_id, college.title, college.category, college.name, college.image, college.content, college.offer, college.note, college.price, college.address, college.contact_no, college.email_id, college.timestamp, college.status FROM college WHERE (title LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (category LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (name LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (address LIKE '%".$query."%')
    UNION 
    SELECT coaching.token_id, coaching.id, coaching.ad_id, coaching.title, coaching.category, coaching.name, coaching.image, coaching.content, coaching.offer, coaching.note, coaching.price, coaching.address, coaching.contact_no, coaching.email_id,coaching.timestamp, coaching.status FROM coaching WHERE (title LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (category LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (name LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (address LIKE '%".$query."%')
    UNION 
    SELECT car_showroom.token_id, car_showroom.id, car_showroom.ad_id, car_showroom.title, car_showroom.category, car_showroom.name, car_showroom.image, car_showroom.content, car_showroom.offer, car_showroom.note, car_showroom.price, car_showroom.address, car_showroom.contact_no, car_showroom.email_id, car_showroom.timestamp, car_showroom.status FROM car_showroom WHERE (title LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (category LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (name LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (address LIKE '%".$query."%')
    UNION 
    SELECT electronic.token_id, electronic.id, electronic.ad_id, electronic.title, electronic.category, electronic.name, electronic.image, electronic.content, electronic.offer, electronic.note, electronic.price, electronic.address, electronic.contact_no, electronic.email_id, electronic.timestamp, electronic.status FROM electronic WHERE (title LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (category LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (name LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (address LIKE '%".$query."%')
    UNION 
    SELECT featured_ads.token_id, featured_ads.id, featured_ads.ad_id, featured_ads.title, featured_ads.category, featured_ads.name, featured_ads.image, featured_ads.content, featured_ads.offer, featured_ads.note, featured_ads.price, featured_ads.address, featured_ads.contact_no, featured_ads.email_id, featured_ads.timestamp, featured_ads.status FROM featured_ads WHERE (title LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (category LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (name LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (address LIKE '%".$query."%')
    UNION 
    SELECT  furniture_showroom.token_id, furniture_showroom.id, furniture_showroom.ad_id, furniture_showroom.title, furniture_showroom.category, furniture_showroom.name, furniture_showroom.image, furniture_showroom.content, furniture_showroom.offer, furniture_showroom.note, furniture_showroom.price, furniture_showroom.address, furniture_showroom.contact_no, furniture_showroom.email_id, furniture_showroom.timestamp, furniture_showroom.status FROM furniture_showroom WHERE (title LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (category LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (name LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (address LIKE '%".$query."%')
    UNION 
    SELECT hospital.token_id, hospital.id, hospital.ad_id, hospital.title, hospital.category, hospital.name, hospital.image, hospital.content, hospital.offer, hospital.note, hospital.price, hospital.address, hospital.contact_no, hospital.email_id, hospital.timestamp, hospital.status FROM hospital WHERE (title LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (category LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (name LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (address LIKE '%".$query."%')
    UNION 
    SELECT job.token_id, job.id, job.ad_id, job.title, job.category, job.name, job.image, job.content, job.offer, job.note, job.price, job.address, job.contact_no, job.email_id, job.timestamp, job.status FROM job WHERE (title LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (category LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (name LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (address LIKE '%".$query."%')
    UNION 
    SELECT mobile_shop.token_id, mobile_shop.id, mobile_shop.ad_id, mobile_shop.title, mobile_shop.category, mobile_shop.name, mobile_shop.image, mobile_shop.content, mobile_shop.offer, mobile_shop.note, mobile_shop.price, mobile_shop.address, mobile_shop.contact_no, mobile_shop.email_id, mobile_shop.timestamp, mobile_shop.status FROM mobile_shop WHERE (title LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (category LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (name LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (address LIKE '%".$query."%')
    UNION 
    SELECT pets_shops.token_id, pets_shops.id, pets_shops.ad_id, pets_shops.title, pets_shops.category, pets_shops.name, pets_shops.image, pets_shops.content, pets_shops.offer, pets_shops.note, pets_shops.price, pets_shops.address, pets_shops.contact_no, pets_shops.email_id, pets_shops.timestamp, pets_shops.status FROM pets_shops WHERE (title LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (category LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (name LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (address LIKE '%".$query."%')
    UNION 
    SELECT play_school.token_id, play_school.id, play_school.ad_id, play_school.title, play_school.category, play_school.name, play_school.image, play_school.content, play_school.offer, play_school.note, play_school.price, play_school.address, play_school.contact_no, play_school.email_id, play_school.timestamp, play_school.status FROM play_school WHERE (title LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (category LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (name LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (address LIKE '%".$query."%')
    UNION 
    SELECT popular_ads.token_id, popular_ads.id, popular_ads.ad_id, popular_ads.title, popular_ads.category, popular_ads.name, popular_ads.image, popular_ads.content, popular_ads.offer, popular_ads.note, popular_ads.price, popular_ads.address, popular_ads.contact_no, popular_ads.email_id, popular_ads.timestamp, popular_ads.status FROM popular_ads WHERE (title LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (category LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (name LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (address LIKE '%".$query."%')
    UNION 
    SELECT real_estate.token_id, real_estate.id, real_estate.ad_id, real_estate.title, real_estate.category, real_estate.name, real_estate.image, real_estate.content, real_estate.offer, real_estate.note, real_estate.price, real_estate.address, real_estate.contact_no, real_estate.email_id, real_estate.timestamp, real_estate.status FROM real_estate WHERE (title LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (category LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (name LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (address LIKE '%".$query."%')
    UNION 
    SELECT services.token_id, services.id, services.ad_id, services.title, services.category, services.name, services.image, services.content, services.offer, services.note, services.price, services.address, services.contact_no, services.email_id, services.timestamp, services.status FROM services WHERE (title LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (category LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (name LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (address LIKE '%".$query."%')
    UNION 
    SELECT shopping_store.token_id, shopping_store.id, shopping_store.ad_id, shopping_store.title, shopping_store.category, shopping_store.name, shopping_store.image, shopping_store.content, shopping_store.offer, shopping_store.note, shopping_store.price, shopping_store.address, shopping_store.contact_no, shopping_store.email_id, shopping_store.timestamp, shopping_store.status FROM shopping_store WHERE (title LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (category LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (name LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (address LIKE '%".$query."%')
    UNION 
    SELECT stationary_shops.token_id, stationary_shops.id, stationary_shops.ad_id, stationary_shops.title, stationary_shops.category, stationary_shops.name, stationary_shops.image, stationary_shops.content, stationary_shops.offer, stationary_shops.note, stationary_shops.price, stationary_shops.address, stationary_shops.contact_no, stationary_shops.email_id, stationary_shops.timestamp, stationary_shops.status FROM stationary_shops WHERE (title LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (category LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (name LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (address LIKE '%".$query."%')
    UNION 
    SELECT sweet_shop.token_id, sweet_shop.id, sweet_shop.ad_id, sweet_shop.title, sweet_shop.category, sweet_shop.name, sweet_shop.image, sweet_shop.content, sweet_shop.offer, sweet_shop.note, sweet_shop.price, sweet_shop.address, sweet_shop.contact_no, sweet_shop.email_id, sweet_shop.timestamp, sweet_shop.status FROM sweet_shop WHERE (title LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (category LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (name LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (address LIKE '%".$query."%')
    UNION 
    SELECT trading_ads.token_id, trading_ads.id, trading_ads.ad_id, trading_ads.title, trading_ads.category, trading_ads.name, trading_ads.image, trading_ads.content, trading_ads.offer, trading_ads.note, trading_ads.price, trading_ads.address, trading_ads.contact_no, trading_ads.email_id, trading_ads.timestamp, trading_ads.status FROM trading_ads WHERE (title LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (category LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (name LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (address LIKE '%".$query."%')");

    $result->execute();
    $row = $result->fetch();
    $rowCoun=$result->rowCount();
    if($rowCoun>0){
      for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
        if($row['status']=='Active'){
          echo $row['title'];
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
?>
```

everything is fine and also data fetch from tables but problem is first entry in table not showing if i `echo $rowCoun=$result->rowCount();` its return 4 row, and also 4 entry in table , but result is showing only 3 entry, can anyone help to fix it. Thanks....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you fetch data once, Try to remove the first `fetch()`

```
$result->execute();

$rowCoun = $result->rowCount();

if ($rowCoun > 0){
  while($row = $result->fetch()) {
    if($row['status'] == 'Active') {
      echo $row['title'];
    }
  }
}
```